# Testing several IntegrityErrors in the same Django unittest test case

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-models

I'm trying to run the following Django unittest:

```
class MyModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_failed_duplicate(self):
        m = MyModel.objects.create(a='a', b='a')
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            MyModel.objects.create(a='a', b='b')
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            MyModel.objects.create(a='a', b='c')
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            MyModel.objects.create(a='a', b='d')
```

There are several tests that all should fail due to violating a uniqueness constraint on field `a`. (I've obfuscated the assertions a bit, but they all test different values of `a` that should fail.)

However, when running I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 21, in test_failed_duplicate
    MyModel.objects.create(a='a', b='c')
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is that:

1. For performance reasons, `TestCase` tests run inside a transaction.
2. The raising of an `IntegrityError` will spoil the current transaction (more precisely, the current atomic block), regardless of whether or not it is caught.

So, in your code, the first `assertRaises` works correctly, but because an `IntegrityError` was raised the transaction becomes spoiled. When you try to access the database with the next `create()` you get the `TransactionManagementError`. See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21540) for more information.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Inherit from `TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase`. This uses table truncation instead of transactions to reset the databse, so you won't have this problem.
2. Run each of your `create()` tests inside a new atomic block. You can see an example in the ticket, and a broader description in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic).

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.